# Hypothesis Test for Ranked Preference?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, survey, friedman-test

I am conducting a survey where people are required to rank 3 different designs from 1st to 3rd. For example, there are 3 designs - A, B and C. Participants are required to rank them in order of preference, e.g.

```
A: 3rd 
B: 1st 
C: 2nd
```

How should I conduct a hypothesis test to see if people prefer design A over the rest?

I came across the Friedman test which mentions that measured values across the 3 groups (in this case, designs) are correlated. However, in my scenario, they are mutually exclusive within the same participant, e.g. if someone chooses design A as 1st, they cannot choose designs B and C as 1st. Is the Friedman test still applicable?

I also came across posts that recommended doing the Friedman test, followed by the Wilcoxon-test to first figure out if there are statistical differences between the groups, then doing pairwise comparisons. Is it possible to compare Design 1 vs Design 2+3 directly, such that my alternative hypothesis would be Design 1 is preferred over both Designs 2 & 3?

I was thinking if I could calculate the averages of 2 & 3 together, then followed by design 1 and comparing them against each other directly using the Wilcoxon Signed Rank test.

Comment: A problem here is that you need to operationalise your null hypothesis better. If you just say "people prefer design A", well, you have the data, some do, some don't, that is that, and you won't be able to show that those who didn't list A on top in fact should've done that. Possible operationalisations would be for example that the probability to prefer A is the biggest of the three, or you set up a model that ranks the three options and somehow specifies probabilities for all deviations, and then you can test whether A is top in the model, but there may be various options for doing this.

Comment: The Friedman test will test the null hypothesis that there is no systematic difference between the three designs, which is probably weaker than what you want (you are probably aware of this because you mention testing 1 vs. 2&3 afterwards; unfortunately you still have dependence there so Wilcoxon won't work). By the way also testing 1 against the average of 2&3 may be weaker than what you want. Note that if 1 is better than 2&3 on average, 1 may still be worse than one of them alone.

Comment: Would it be enough to reject significantly that A, B, and C are all the same (by Friedman), and then to show that A is (much?) better than B and C just from probability estimators/data visualisation? Some statisticians think, for good reason, that many people are too obsessed with significance and testing, and running tests conditionally on other tests comes with problems.

Comment: If you're trying to use the signed rank test as a post hoc for the Friedman, note that the tests don't correspond; they see the data differently.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Friedman+post+hoc